# Please use different color on 'seen' anchor tag

Tags: feature-request, design

Until recently the color of Questions in the main pages of Questions of dba.stackexchange [*eg*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql+or+mariadb?sort=newest&pagesize=50) had had significance.  Now a Question that I have opened is the same color as one I have not yet looked at.

I have used this to avoid unnecessarily starting to answer a Question that I have already answered.  StackOverflow and some other sibling sites continue to have the color difference.  Please revert.

Comment: Hey Rick! Questions specific to a particular site should be asked on their meta. I promise we see them here, too. Thanks for letting us know. I'll see if we can look into this.

Comment: @Catija - Thanks for the migration.  Now I see the pattern for tacking on "meta".